# Scala - Drop all mappings whose keys are not in a given set

Tags: scala, dictionary, set

What is the idiomatic way to compute a map whose mappings are the mappings of another map, without the mappings whose keys are members of a given set?

For example, from the given set and map below:

```
Map(A -> v, B -> w, C -> x, D -> y, E -> z)
Set(A, C, E)
```

our function would yield:

```
Map(B -> w, D -> y)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just filter it:

```
val map = Map("A" -> "v", "B" -> "w", "C" -> "x", "D" -> "y", "E" -> "z")
val set = Set("A", "C", "E")

map.filterKeys(!set.contains(_))
```

Results in:

```
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(B -> w, D -> y)
```

Comment: Please be aware that filterKeys returns a view. So this might produce a memory leak.

Comment: @RüdigerKlaehn, in which case `map.filterNot(x=>set(x._1)) `. The original can be shorter, too `map.filterKeys(!set(_)) `

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `--` method from [Map](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Map)

> def --(xs: GenTraversableOnce[A]): Map[A, B]
>
> Creates a new collection from this collection by removing all elements
>   of another collection.

```
scala> val map = Map("A" -> "v", "B" -> "w", "C" -> "x", "D" -> "y", "E" -> "z")
map: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(E -> z, A -> v, B -> w, C -> x, D -> y)

scala> val set = Set("A", "C", "E")
set: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(A, C, E)

scala> val filter = map -- set
filter: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(B -> w, D -> y)
```